# Magnetising a needle with static electricity using silk cloth

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, particle-physics, magnetic-fields, electricity

A nautical navigation textbook on my table says that we can magnetise a non-magnetised needle by rubbing it with a silk cloth. I decided to cross check on the internet, and found some experts calling it off as bullshit. They said that it will make the needle charged with static electricity, as the friction will cause the electrons to transfer between surfaces, and the force of a magnetic field does not affect a static object. So if any of you can conform/reject this notion, then please do.

Apart from that, I tried to make sense of the fact that a capacitor creates an instantaneous current when connected to ground. I also know that a magnet can be made by placing a ferrous demagnetised object in the center of a copper coil that has an electric current running through it.

So if we're stranded at sea with our compass demagnetised, can't we make use of two dissimilar materials by rubbing them, then connecting the resultant static charged object to a copper coil that is ground, placing a demagnetised needle in the center of the coil and finally, closing the switch to let the charged object discharge?

As a needle has such low volume and mass, I believe a few such discharging cycles could effectively find us north again!

Will this work?

P.s. If you close this question as off-topic, at the very least leave a reason.

[ EDIT #1 ] User @phillip-petty has suggested that the effect of self inductance in the coil will theoretically get rid of the possibility of (strong) magnetisation, due to the short time the current flows in static discharge. What if we use a hand-crank triboelectric generator - e.g. the one with a glass flywheel with a leather flap pressed against it? That will generate a current as long as you spin the flywheel and should overcome self inductance! And yet, no need for magnets to make a magnet.

[EDIT #2] I have been told that ROLLING the needle against the silk will magnetise the needle, as long as both objects keep their charge. The idea is that the opposite charges of both will always try to stay as close as possible, regardless of the needle's orientation. Thus, if we roll the needle, it is effectively moving the charge around it, just like an electromagnet's coils move electrons in the coil around the core magnet. I drew these diagrams for those who check out this post in the future. Can the experts confirm this notion? Will it magnetise the needle as intended?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You know, I wanted to suggest the possibility of a hand-crank generator in my post, but I decided to keep it short. Faraday showed that you could electrolyze equivalent quantities of a solution using a battery of a given strength, and then cranking a triboelectric generator a certain number of turns. It seems like it would work in the needle case too.

Comment: @phillip-petty I tried to find the Faraday demonstration you mentioned on the net but can't seem to find it. Are you sure he didn't use an electroMAGNETIC hand crank generator, rather than TRIBOelectric? Is there a name for that experiment or device he used so I could search it more specifically? Also, check out my new edit #2 and tell me what to you think of it.

Comment: Sorry, I looked over my notes and found the section I was referencing. It does seem to be an electromagnetic generator. The references are in "Experimental Researches in Electricity" Volume 1, Third Series, Paragraph 290; then again in the Fifth Series, Paragraph 450.

Comment: @phillip-petty So. What about the rolling of the needle against charged silk :P

Comment: @ElFlea Why not to do some experiment instead of discussion?

Comment: 1. [Please do not let posts look like revision histories](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5886/50583). 2. Please omit meta commentary like "if you vote to close this question...". It has nothing to do with the physics content of the post and it is implicitly understood anyways. (Additionally, no close vote was ever cast on this question). 3. The large pictures are rather annoying to scroll past - perhaps you could embed some smaller versions? 4. Calling people "greedy" in your bounty notice is not necessarily the most effective strategy to attract high-quality answers.

Comment: @ElFlea I have updated my answer with an interesting twist I have found. I encourage you to do the actual experiment and report here back.

Comment: @ElFlea Yes you are absolutely correct. Only a specific end of the permanently magnetized needle will always align with the magnetic N end of the of the compass needle. I used a small aquarium for my experiments filled about 1/4 with water so to prevent any air currents that could affect the floating needle.   If you position the compass on the aquarium and turn the aquarium at a random angle you will see that the permanently magnetized floating needle will re align each time to the compass new  position. Let;s continue the comments here because the previous thread of comments is overpopulated

Comment: @ElFlea I used an eye glasses wiper cloth for triboelectrically charging the needle. Also allow a safe distance from the aquarium walls. Since, the needle is also in addition electrostatically charged and this could affect the motion of the needle. Finally, I placed the needle on a small piece of air bubble sheet https://www.starpackairbubble.com/air-bubble-sheets.html . Please report back here the results by answering your own question :)

Comment: @ElFlea Please read my updated answer (28 Nov) for latest experimental results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, an electron has both an electric charge *-e* and an intrinsic magnetic dipole moment N-S, *μ*.

Static electricity in the needle means that you rearrange the charges in the needle and you spatially split them in negative region (one end of the needle) and positive (other end of the needle). Negative region is the region which has an excess of free electrons where positive region is the region which has a lack in the number of electrons. This charge imbalance causes the electrostatic charge and field of the needle when rubbing it with a cloth.

However in this kind of charge the magnetic moments of the electrons are randomly scattered in any direction therefore there is no magnetization of the needle thus it CANNOT SENSE and respond to the magnetic field of the Earth.

Magnetostatics are different. Charges (i.e. electrons) are evenly distributed inside the matter of the metal needle. If you can find a way assuming the needle material is ferromagnetic to re-orient all magnetic moments of the unpaired electrons to align to the same direction then you will magnetize the needle and it will sense the magnetic field of the Earth and needle will respond by aligning to the magnetic field of the Earth!

See below illustration of the difference between electrostatically charged matter and magnetically dipole charged matter (i.e. magnetized):

[image: Magnetostatic Vs. Electrostatic charge]

Green arrows represent the magnetic moments N-S direction of the electrons.

It all depends on the material if it is magnetizable or electrostatic chargeable? There are materials that respond both to magnetic and electrostatic charging but eletrostatically charging a material will not make it magnetic and magnetizing it will not make it electrostatic.

**Note:** Even, when uniformly rubbing the needle with a cloth so that you end up with a uniformly electrostatically charged needle (i.e. the whole needle surface lacks in electrons or has an excess of electrons relative to other material objects), it will still have its charges' magnetic moments randomly oriented and therefore you cannot achieve magnetization of the needle by triboelectric effect. *Electrostatic charging* is about spatially transferring whole charges from one place to the other. *Magnetostatic charging* is about turning the charge's magnetic moments so that they face all to the same direction. It's two different things which each requires a different procedure to be accomplished assuming the specific material's atomic structure allows it.

**Update 22 Nov 2021:**

Although the above answer is describing the general case farther investigation revealed this article I cannot dismiss lightly since in almost every rule there are exceptions and we must be open minded:

[Survival Gear: How To Make A Compass](https://www.outdoorlife.com/blogs/survivalist/2012/10/survival-gear-how-make-compass/)

It says: *"you can magnetize a needle by rubbing it against your hair, some animal fur, or silk. Carefully hold the sharp point of the needle and rub just the eye of the needle 50 to 100 times against the hair, fur, or silk."*

In first glance this may seem ridiculous but there is possibility to both electrically charge in this case the needle and also magnetize it!

This is because it says to only rub the eye, the very tip of the needle. It is possible in such as small volume (less than a few microns cross-section) the electrostatically accumulated charges in there to end up also more or less with aligned magnetic moments in the same direction. Therefore **aligned** [magnetic domains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_domain) are formed at the very tip of the needle that would act as a magnet.

Only an actual experiment can tell with the needle seeking the Earth's magnetic south pole (i.e. located close to the Geographic North pole).

I expect this magnetization effect to be very small, if any at all, but a needle floating on water, could work.

**Update 26 Nov 2021:**

I did an experiment linked on the comments below (please read also my related comments below addressed to @Ed Flea, to avoid any misunderstandings). Nothing conclusive unless repeated many times and replicated also by others, although it seems at first glance a positive result.

****Update 28 Nov 2021:****

Okay, I have repeated this experiment many times now and my results show conclusively that you **CANNOT magnetize** the eye of a needle by static electricity (i.e. triboelectric effect) as some of these survival guides magazines claim.

The first experiment run I've got a positive result must have been a fluke, somehow accidentally the needle must have been magnetized. I bought some new needles and repeated the experiment 10 times, always with the same result. No magnetization of the needle.

Conclusion: You cannot magnetize a needle by static electricity.

Comment: I have updated my answer with an interesting twist I have found. I encourage everyone to do the actual experiment and report here back. If the experimental results turn out to be statistically positive, given my explanation to this effect, I suggest we name this effect as "El Flea effect" honoring the person here who brought the subject :)

Comment: Of course there is also the possibility such an small spherical area to get magnetized from the own magnetic field of the Earth (~50μΤ) by swinging the needle 50-100 times and not due any triboelectric effect.

Comment: If the material is ferromagnetic the domains are there already.  You do not form them by an external process.

Comment: And any experiment should check first that the needle is not magnetized BEFORE rubbing.

Comment: @nasu The magnetic domains are already there you are right. I meant aligned magnetic domains. I have this now edited in my answer. "And any experiment should check first that the needle is not magnetized BEFORE rubbing" ha haa Good point!

Comment: Also make sure using a second identical needle and a magnet that your needle is ferromagnetic. If it is made out by stainless steel it cannot be magnetized.

Comment: @markoul11 I understand the theoretical impossibility of electrostatic field to magnetise an object, but what about the rolling phenomenon I demonstrate in the edit? That is moving charges with respect to the object, which is essentially the same as an electromagnet?! That should align the magnetic dipoles of a ferromagnetic needle, right?

Comment: @markoul11 I wish I could award you the +50 looking at the effort you put in your answer, but seems like you didn't read the whole question. Your answer is reinforcing my assumed stance, but I want to know if the rolling phenomenon would work as MOVING charges, i.e. electricity.

Comment: @markoul11 About charging only the tip of the needle, why do you think that an electrostatically charged tip has any more reason to align its magnetic dipoles than an electrostatically charged full needle? I mean you rely on randomness, so randomness is just as... random... in a tip as in a full? Maybe I misunderstand.

Comment: @Ed Flea Sorry for not seeing your comments in time. Not randomness, but probability. Squeezing the volume space increases the probability some magnetic domains to end up aligned. Rubbing electrons, around the needle will not create the same magnetic field as uniformly heads on spiraling electrons in a coil which creates a straight flux lines magnetic field inside the coil where the core is (object to be magnetized). It will just accumulate charges on the surface of the needle with their magnetic moments randomly scattered. It is not so much about bounty but more becuase I found it interesting

Comment: @markoul11 I believe you think I mean rolling the needle while it's in actual physical contact with the cloth. That's not what I mean. I mean to roll the (charged) needle slightly away (but not too away that the electrostatic forces can't be felt) from the (opposite charged) cloth such that the field will always ensure that the (+) and (-) charges of the needle don't move in space and we make the needle turn relative to its own (pseudo immobilised) charges. That would basically be charges moving from the needle's frame of reference - electricity!

Comment: @markoul11 I also realize that something must keep the needle charged as the charges will dissipate to the environment slowly. But we could always charge it by rubbing physically with the silk cloth and then moving it away slightly and rolling it, rinse repeat.

Comment: @ElFlea This theory of yours can only be answered by statistical experiments. These are difficult. I did an experiment of my own, got a result but that does not mean that there is something conclusive. There are many parameters to be eliminated to make an actual control experiment. I tested before the needle if it was magnetized with a compass and it was not responding. Then I rubbed the needle many times. Here is the result (which means nothing if not done many times and also replicated by others). https://drive.google.com/file/d/1myDf0cThRdUk61OhfqG7pDS9NaBBKOgr/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @ElFlea In my previous comment linked experiment video, only the tip of the needle (and not the head) was aligning with the N tip of the compass therefore the needle is definitely a magnet. The first time where I put the needle on water to float without any triboelectric rubbing, although it is hard too see in the video, the needle was moving away from alignment with the compass and passed away fro the alignment direction, therefore I presumed that the needle was not magnetized at that point. After, I rubbed the needle many times, it start responding correctly and aligning with the compass.

Comment: @markoul11 It does not mean nothing my friend. You have started the process of discovery of the El Flea effect for yourself and the physics world at large! I'd suggest linking this video in your answer. My mind = blown. I will repeat this experiment on my own and self answer this beautiful question with the experimental proofs. Ground breaking...

Comment: @ElFlea he he! Hold on your horses!

Comment: @ElFlea Also be careful. I ferromagnetic needle non magnetized does not mean that it will not move a compass when approached, It will still when close enough move the compass since it concentrates the flux from the Earth's magnetic field. This however does not mean that it has become a permanent magnet dipole. Ferromagnetic matter is always attracted by any pole of the permanent  magnet and never repelled. In order to see if the needle has become a permanent magnet using a compass, the compass must be attracted from the one side of the needle and repelled by the other side of the needle.

Comment: @markoul11 I'll keep that in mind. But if we consider the alignment of the needle with Earth's magnetic South, without any magnets or metals near it, that surely would mean it is magnetised. If I understand correctly, the ferromagnetic needle will not align the same way every time, to one pole of Earth's magnetic field unless it is indeed a permanent magnet, right? An unmagnetised needle can be attracted to Earth's magnetic south/north by the head/tip/side randomly, because the magnetism can be induced in any place, in any direction. Do correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Let's consider using a battery to create the current in the coil. To magnetise the needle, you would insert the needle into the coil, then connect the battery. Connecting the battery caused the current to change from zero to its maximum value which caused a magnetic field to build up inside the coil. When the battery is disconnected, the magnetic field falls to zero again.

During this process, the coil is also affected by self-inductance. Each section of coil experiences inductance due to the changing magnetic field created by the adjacent sections of coil. The self-inductance doesn't matter with the battery because the current flows long enough for the self-inductance affects to fall off.

In the case of using static discharge, the current doesn't flow long enough for self-inductance affects to fall off (I haven't tried to quantify this). I don't think one could achieve a significant enough charge by triboelectric affect to achieve a meaningful magnetic field inside the coil, but even if one could, I think the self-inductance of the coil would make the magnetic field negligible.

That being said, I haven't tried the experiment.

Comment: To magnetize the needle as a compass needle by using a magnetic field the magnetic flux lines must be along the length of the needle. This is done by positioning the needle at the center of an electric solenoid. Just feeding the needle with current will create a concentric circular magnetic field around the needle perpendicular to the length of the needle which does not magnetize the needle after the current is cut.